# PineScript Highest Bar between two zones

Tags: pine-script

Update 1:

Let me try to modify my question as i think it was not very clear what i wanted to achieve and I also try another solution
So my goal is to Find the Highest High candle ( green circled candle) on a specific zone which is the green zone on my screenshot below .

[image]

For now what i did is a loop when d[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McYT7.png) < 50 and d > 50 then i loop bar by bar to find the index of the highest bar
Then when i find it i do a barssince(d[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McYT7.png) < 50 and d > 50) to spot how many candle i have on the green zone
and finally i will substract the barssince number with the bar index of the highest point and voila
So clearer example
Let s say my green zone when i loop i find that the 4th bar is the highest one after i do a barssince that tell me i have
7 bars in total on the green zone so to know which is the highest bar within that zone i would do 7-4 = 3
so if i do a offset of -3 i should find the highest candle but it doesn t work .
As you can see on the screenshot if I find that the candle that should be highlighted in purple color should be a -3 off set starting from the orange highlighted zone but it does a - 5 so i am unsure what is going on

[image]

Here is my coding attempt

```
//@version=4
study(title="trytofindhighesthigh", shorttitle="trytofindhighesthigh", max_bars_back=5000)

//Stochastic 
smooth = input(2, minval=1), K = input(3, minval=1), D=input(5,minval=1)
hhs=highest(high,K)
ll=lowest(low,K)
k = sma((close-ll)/(hhs-ll)*100, smooth)
d = sma(k, D)
up3 = d > 50
down3 = d < 50
mycolor3 = up3 ? color.green : down3 ? color.red : color.blue
backgroundColour = mycolor3
//color the chart depending on the stochastic
bgcolor(color=backgroundColour, transp=85)


// plotchar(crossabove,char='o')

var counter = 0.0
var keephigh = 0.0
var keepbarindex = 0.0
var h_indx = 0
if d > 50 and counter == 0 
    counter := counter + 1
    keephigh := high
    keepbarindex := bar_index
    h_indx := 0
else if d > 50 and counter > 0 
    counter := counter + 1
    if  high >= keephigh 
        keephigh := high
        keepbarindex := bar_index
        h_indx := h_indx + 1 
if d < 50
    counter := 0



mycolor4 = if d[1] > 50 and d < 50
    color.orange
//color the chart depending on the stochastic
bgcolor(color=mycolor4, transp=85)

mycolor5 = if d[1] > 50 and d < 50
    color.purple
bgcolor(color=mycolor5, transp=85,offset=-1 * ( barssince(d[1] < 50 and d >50 ) - h_indx) )
plot(-1 * (barssince(d[1] < 50 and d >50 ) - h_indx) )
```

-- End of Update 1

I would like to find the highest high between two zones but I am having a hard time to understand how to achieve it

My zone are delimited between 1 and 2 ( highlight in green on my chart ) but i am not sure how to achieve it. I tried to do a combination barssince , highest and bar_index but failed to achieve it

The output i would like is to put a label on the candle that forms the highest high on the green zone

[image]

Now what i tried to do is that i look on that particular zone to find the N candle that makes the highest point

To be able to do it I have done a loop into the candle to find the highest high and store the candle with the highest high.
Then I would do a barsince

My coding attempt

```
//@version=4
study(title="whatever", shorttitle="Colored SMA", max_bars_back=5000,overlay=true)

// SMA
smaplot = input (false, title="Show MA on chart")
len2 = input(50, minval=1, title="ma Length")
src2 = close
out2 = sma(src2, len2)
colorsma = if out2 > out2[1]
    color.green
else if out2 < out2[1]
    color.red
else
    color.blue
plot(out2, color=colorsma )

//Stochastic 
smooth = input(2, minval=1), K = input(3, minval=1), D=input(5,minval=1)
hhs=highest(high,K)
ll=lowest(low,K)
k = sma((close-ll)/(hhs-ll)*100, smooth)
d = sma(k, D)
up3 = d > 50
down3 = d < 50
mycolor3 = up3 ? color.green : down3 ? color.red : color.blue
backgroundColour = mycolor3
//color the chart depending on the stochastic
bgcolor(color=backgroundColour, transp=85)


// color when the candle cross the 50
//crossabove
// colors1 = if d[1] < 50 and d > 50
//     color.yellow
// bgcolor(color=colors1, transp=85)
// //crossbelow
// colors2 = if d[1] > 50 and d < 50
//     color.blue
// bgcolor(color=colors2, transp=85)

// var test = 0
// test := if d[1] > 50 and d < 50
//     1 

// plot(barssince(d[1] < 50 and d > 50 and d[1] > 50 and d < 50),color=color.orange)

crossabove = if d[1] < 50 and d > 50
    1
else
    0
crossbelow = if d[1] > 50 and d < 50
    2 
else
    0

plotchar(crossabove==1 ,title = "Crossabove" , char="1",color=color.green,location=location.belowbar,transp=0)
plotchar(crossbelow==2 ,title = "Crossbelow" , char="2",color=color.green,location=location.belowbar,transp=0)
temp_BarSincecrossabove = barssince(crossabove==1) + 3
temp_BarSincecrossabove_2 =  temp_BarSincecrossabove <= 0 ?  1 : temp_BarSincecrossabove
temp_BarSincecrossabove_3 = na(temp_BarSincecrossabove_2) ? 1 : temp_BarSincecrossabove_2
highestpointBarSincecrossabove = highest(high,temp_BarSincecrossabove_3)
highestBarSincecrossabove = highestbars(high,temp_BarSincecrossabove_3)
plot(highestpointBarSincecrossabove)
// plotchar(bar_index[-highestBarSincecrossabove] ,title = "Highest High", text= '[HH]',color=color.green,location=location.abovebar,transp=0)
```

Or maybe i need to find the swing high keep track of it , i am unsure at this point. The question that will follow up is how to check the highest high between two different green zone but i guess i first need to figure what logic could be used for this question

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here we monitor the hi/lo when we are in the appropriate zone, and reposition the label when we find a new hi/lo. Because we're using labels, which is the only way in Pine to achieve what you need, you will only see the last ~50 labels.

While they are not needed for the labels to print, the `hi` and `lo` variables keep track of the values so you can reuse them if you need to:

```
//@version=4
study(title="whatever", shorttitle="Colored SMA", max_bars_back=5000,overlay=true)

// SMA
smaplot = input (false, title="Show MA on chart")
len2 = input(50, minval=1, title="ma Length")
src2 = close
out2 = sma(src2, len2)
colorsma = if out2 > out2[1]
    color.green
else if out2 < out2[1]
    color.red
else
    color.blue
plot(out2, color=colorsma )

//Stochastic 
smooth = input(2, minval=1), K = input(3, minval=1), D=input(5,minval=1)
hhs=highest(high,K)
ll=lowest(low,K)
k = sma((close-ll)/(hhs-ll)*100, smooth)
d = sma(k, D)
up3 = d > 50
down3 = d < 50
mycolor3 = up3 ? color.green : down3 ? color.red : color.blue
backgroundColour = mycolor3
//color the chart depending on the stochastic
bgcolor(color=backgroundColour, transp=85)

var float hi = na
var float lo = na
var label labelHi = na
var label labelLo = na
// Detect crosses.
xUp = crossover( d, 50)
xDn = crossunder(d, 50)

// When entering new zone, reset hi/lo and create a new label.
if xUp
    hi      := high
    labelHi := label.new(bar_index, na, "▼", yloc = yloc.abovebar, color = #000000, textcolor = color.lime, style = label.style_none)
else if xDn
    lo      := low
    labelLo := label.new(bar_index, na, "▲", yloc = yloc.belowbar, color = #000000, textcolor = color.red, style = label.style_none)

// When in a zone, continuously monitor for newer hi/lo and if one is found, move label.
if up3 and high > hi
    hi      := high
    label.set_xy(labelHi, bar_index, na)
else if down3 and low < lo
    lo      := low
    label.set_xy(labelLo, bar_index, na)

plotchar(xUp, title = "Crossabove" , char="1",color=color.green,location=location.belowbar,transp=0)
plotchar(xDn, title = "Crossbelow" , char="2",color=color.green,location=location.belowbar,transp=0)
```

[image]

Comment: is there a way to get more than 50 labels!!

Comment: Not currently. We have asked the Pine team for more, but more work is required with the management of memory used by scripts before increasing the limit. We should be able to use more labels in a few months.

Comment: Is there any other workaround to get the labelling for more than 50 labels?
for example store the bar_index in a variable and use barssince to plot the labels?